# How to force picture select library in landscape?

Tags: android

I can use the following way to open picture select library, but is there any way to force it in landscape?

```
intent = (new Intent("android.intent.action.PICK")).setType("image/*");
fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, 9162);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest set orientation of that activity to landscape? For instance

```
<activity
android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
...
```

Comment: This does not work. By the way, the correct way using android.intent.action.PICK is in action, like "<action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />", rather than in activity

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought it was an activity, sorry cannot help bro.